# I can't use "$" dollar sign in React JS ClassName

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-class-based-component

I tried to Use "$" Dollar Sign in React JS Class Name

```
`
p class Name={'"chat-message" ${true && "enter code herechat-reciever"}'}>
`
```

When I used above code I doesn't work correctly.
Here I'm Using Class Name in WhatsApp Clone.
I want to use JavaScript for Whether This Message was sent by me or Received.
Also I'm want to make second Class as True

Answer (score 0):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) need to delimited with `backticks`

```
p class Name={`"chat-message" ${true && "enter code here`chat-reciever"}`}
```

Comment: I can't understand plz explain well

Comment: A linked the Template literals docs in the answer, you can take a look.

Comment: Again? May I know the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I'm new Stack Overflow

Comment: No, sorry it wasn't meant for you. I was talking with "some-body" else